# When did Jesus cleanse the leper?

Tags: contradiction

According to Matthew, the leper was cleansed **after** the Sermon on the mount. However, Luke has it **before** the Sermon on the mount.

Matthew 5:1-3 and following:

> <sup>**1**</sup> And seeing the multitudes, he went up into a mountain: and when he was set, his disciples came unto him: <sup>**2**</sup> And he opened his mouth, and taught them, saying, <sup>**3**</sup> Blessed are the poor in spirit: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.

Then, later Matthew 8:1-4

> <sup>**1**</sup> When he was come down from the mountain, great multitudes followed him. <sup>**2**</sup> And, behold, there came a leper and worshipped him, saying, Lord, if thou wilt, thou canst make me clean. <sup>**3**</sup> And Jesus put forth his hand, and touched him, saying, I will; be thou clean. And immediately his leprosy was cleansed. <sup>**4**</sup> And Jesus saith unto him, See thou tell no man; but go thy way, shew thyself to the priest, and offer the gift that Moses commanded, for a testimony unto them.

So the leper was cleansed **after** the Sermon on the Mount.

However, Luke, a renowned historian, disagreed.

Luke 5:12-14

> <sup>**12**</sup> And it came to pass, when he was in a certain city, behold a man full of leprosy: who seeing Jesus fell on his face, and besought him, saying, Lord, if thou wilt, thou canst make me clean. <sup>**13**</sup> And he put forth his hand, and touched him, saying, I will: be thou clean. And immediately the leprosy departed from him. <sup>**14**</sup> And he charged him to tell no man: but go, and shew thyself to the priest, and offer for thy cleansing, according as Moses commanded, for a testimony unto them.

then, **after** the leper was cleansed, Jesus had the Sermon on the Mount,

Luke 6:20-49

> <sup>**20**</sup> And he lifted up his eyes on his disciples, and said, Blessed be ye poor: for yours is the kingdom of God. <sup>**21**</sup> Blessed are ye that hunger now: for ye shall be filled. Blessed are ye that weep now: for ye shall laugh. <sup>**22**</sup> Blessed are ye, when men shall hate you, and when they shall separate you from their company, and shall reproach you, and cast out your name as evil, for the Son of man's sake. <sup>**23**</sup> Rejoice ye in that day, and leap for joy: for, behold, your reward is great in heaven: for in the like manner did their fathers unto the prophets. <sup>**24**</sup> But woe unto you that are rich! for ye have received your consolation. <sup>**25**</sup> Woe unto you that are full! for ye shall hunger. Woe unto you that laugh now! for ye shall mourn and weep. <sup>**26**</sup> Woe unto you, when all men shall speak well of you! for so did their fathers to the false prophets. <sup>**27**</sup> But I say unto you which hear, Love your enemies, do good to them which hate you, <sup>**28**</sup> Bless them that curse you, and pray for them which despitefully use you. <sup>**29**</sup> And unto him that smiteth thee on the one cheek offer also the other; and him that taketh away thy cloak forbid not to take thy coat also. <sup>**30**</sup> Give to every man that asketh of thee; and of him that taketh away thy goods ask them not again. <sup>**31**</sup> And as ye would that men should do to you, do ye also to them likewise. <sup>**32**</sup> For if ye love them which love you, what thank have ye? for sinners also love those that love them. <sup>**33**</sup> And if ye do good to them which do good to you, what thank have ye? for sinners also do even the same. <sup>**34**</sup> And if ye lend to them of whom ye hope to receive, what thank have ye? for sinners also lend to sinners, to receive as much again. <sup>**35**</sup> But love ye your enemies, and do good, and lend, hoping for nothing again; and your reward shall be great, and ye shall be the children of the Highest: for he is kind unto the unthankful and to the evil. <sup>**36**</sup> Be ye therefore merciful, as your Father also is merciful. <sup>**37**</sup> Judge not, and ye shall not be judged: condemn not, and ye shall not be condemned: forgive, and ye shall be forgiven: <sup>**38**</sup> Give, and it shall be given unto you; good measure, pressed down, and shaken together, and running over, shall men give into your bosom. For with the same measure that ye mete withal it shall be measured to you again. <sup>**39**</sup> And he spake a parable unto them, Can the blind lead the blind? shall they not both fall into the ditch? <sup>**40**</sup> The disciple is not above his master: but every one that is perfect shall be as his master. <sup>**41**</sup> And why beholdest thou the mote that is in thy brother's eye, but perceivest not the beam that is in thine own eye? <sup>**42**</sup> Either how canst thou say to thy brother, Brother, let me pull out the mote that is in thine eye, when thou thyself beholdest not the beam that is in thine own eye? Thou hypocrite, cast out first the beam out of thine own eye, and then shalt thou see clearly to pull out the mote that is in thy brother's eye. <sup>**43**</sup> For a good tree bringeth not forth corrupt fruit; neither doth a corrupt tree bring forth good fruit. <sup>**44**</sup> For every tree is known by his own fruit. For of thorns men do not gather figs, nor of a bramble bush gather they grapes. <sup>**45**</sup> A good man out of the good treasure of his heart bringeth forth that which is good; and an evil man out of the evil treasure of his heart bringeth forth that which is evil: for of the abundance of the heart his mouth speaketh. <sup>**46**</sup> And why call ye me, Lord, Lord, and do not the things which I say? <sup>**47**</sup> Whosoever cometh to me, and heareth my sayings, and doeth them, I will shew you to whom he is like: <sup>**48**</sup> He is like a man which built an house, and digged deep, and laid the foundation on a rock: and when the flood arose, the stream beat vehemently upon that house, and could not shake it: for it was founded upon a rock. <sup>**49**</sup> But he that heareth, and doeth not, is like a man that without a foundation built an house upon the earth; against which the stream did beat vehemently, and immediately it fell; and the ruin of that house was great.

So can someone solve this seeming contradiction?

Comment: Luke is quite clear (6:17). He recorded the Sermon on the Plain, not on the Mount. So if the leper was the same man, then Jesus gave the Sermon on the Plain after the Sermon on the Mount.

Comment: @Revelation Lad Thanks for your comment. Same sermon basically just in a different location. I agree with you that Matthew 5 was on a mount, and Luke's was on a plain. I have heard preachers use the same sermon depending on where they are so I don't find this difficult to believe at all. Write an answer to this and I will tag you with best answer.

Comment: @SaberTruthTiger - I have already stated, that the evangelists did not care much for strict chronology but often presented their material in by subject or topic,  rather than time sequence.

Comment: I know they did not care much for strict chronology. They did not care, it's that simple and as a result of their indifference in chronology there were mistakes made. Just because a society sees no trouble with historical inaccuracy does not make an error in their chronology ok.  Harmonizations are a dime a dozen in the world of apologetics and hermeneutics.

Comment: All - different people take different approaches for these things. What is an acceptable harmonisation to one person may not be to another. Let's not insist upon one another that our own approach is the only valid way of approaching the topic. If you have a different perspective, the best way to capture it is to write a high-quality Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"THE leper"? Which leper? Jesus healed more than one leper. He healed ten of them at one time, though only one of them returned from showing himself to the priests to thank Jesus. He healed many other lepers. All of them were obliged by law to show themselves to the priests to confirm being clear of leprosy. In Matthew chapter 11 Jesus himself said,

> "Go and shew John [the Baptist] again those things which ye do hear
> and see: the blind receive their sight, and the lame walk, the lepers
> are cleansed, and the deaf hear, the dead are raised up, and the poor
> have the gospel preached to them. And blessed is he, whosoever shall
> not be offended in me." Matthew 11:4-6

All of those miracles, including healing leprosy, are in the plural. Not all of the miracles of leprosy healing are recorded in all four gospels. How can anyone know if the two accounts you have homed in on are with regard to the same, one healing, the one man? John pointed out:

> "And many other signs truly did Jesus in the presence of his
> disciples, which are not written in this book. But these are written,
> that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and
> that believing ye might have life through his name." John 20:30-31

None of the gospel accounts are biographies of Jesus' life. That is why they cannot be taken as if written in strict chronological order. None of them were. They are designed to prove that the virgin Mary's first-born son truly is the Son of God, and that we must believe in his name to have life eternal.

There is no need to try to harmonise the gospels. But if you insist that they must be harmonised to your satisfaction, in strict chronological order, before you will believe, then you will totally miss the point of the gospel accounts. How can anyone really suppose that dating of individual events in the gospels is the determining factor as to whether they will believe in Jesus or not? We are not given sufficient information to even date Jesus' birth! It's worth heeding Jesus' words (above) "...blessed is he, whosoever shall not be offended in me."

Comment: Why argue that just because people back in the time when Jesus was alive didn't put as much importance on chronology excuse it? If I wrote my biography and I didn't care much for chronological order and as a result In one chapter I wrote "I became a Christian before the War was over" and in another chapter I became a Christian "ten years after the war" that could be harmonized with some effort but any harmonization would be in error. The second would be a contradiction from the first and is false, Just because it was socially acceptable to disregard chronology does not mean that is acceptabl

Comment: A falsehood is a falsehood, no matter how acceptable the society finds that falsehood. No regard for harmony doesn't mean it is correct. If someone was genuinely wrong in what they wrote and years later someone harmonized it that would that mean it was ok? Just because a society doesn't care about accuracy in chronology doesn't mean that society should be judged righteous in their chronology. A mistake is a mistake, no matter how much a society thinks it is alright to make those mistakes.

Comment: ...@Anne how do I mark your answer as the Answer I found satisfactory?

Comment: Good answer.  Well stated. +1.